# Adding a External Reference in asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to add a external control in my mvc3 project. I added the dll in the reference.
But I dont know how to use this reference in my .cshtml.

Sorry but forgot to mention that i add a refernce at web.config present in view but not getting any intellisense of that control

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can simply import the namespace into your view by adding `@using System.Data.Linq` at the top of your view.

However if you want it in all your views then you need to add `<add namespace="System.Data.Linq" />` 
to the web.config in your Views folder.

This way you will not have to import the namespace in every view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the classes from that assembly by importing the relevant namespace to your view (just like in a regular C# file).

```
@using MyNameSpace
```

Comment: Thanks I had done this but I am not getting any intellisense related to that control in my view.

Comment: What do you mean by control? Is it another Razor file?

Comment: No it is a custom control. I had made a control which is inhertied by a textbox. I can easily use this control in my web applications.

Comment: @user1685652 A user control for Web Forms applications?

Answer (score 0):

As a better practice,i usually add the reference on the `web.config located under the Views folder`.Please note this web.config is different from the one on the root level.

Views > Web.config

for example you can add the reference for linq like this in your Views/Web.config

```
<add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
```

what this means is you dont have to explicitly import the reference on the page everytime you need it and you still get to access the assembly.I usually do this to keep my html away from lot of import statements.

You can also import them manually by doing this on your cshtml

> @using assembly namespace

Also dont forget to add the dll reference manually under your references folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
@using Asd.CheckBox;
```

This is my dll `Asd.CheckBox`.